# Incorrect encoding cyrillic symbols in Pydantic json method (Python)

Tags: python, json, encoding, pydantic, cyrillic

Simple example of the problem is given below:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class City(BaseModel):
    name: str

city = City(name="Город")
print(city)  # name='Город'
print(city.json())  # {"name": "\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434"}
```

My system info:

- Windows 11
- Python 3.11.3
- Pydantic 1.10.7
- File .py encoding is UTF-8

Problem remains with any [chcp option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp) (console encoding): 866, 1251, 65001. If I try to write `json()` output into txt file, the output is same \u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434. I would really appreciate if you could help me to fix the root problem. I want this code to output pure json with proper cyrillic symbols.

I've tried:

- Change chcp option
- Change Windows language settings
- Change .py file encoding
- Reinstalled Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's JSON module tries to keep all JSON output within ASCII, which doesn't contain any cyrillic characters.

You can turn off this setting with `ensure_ascii=False`:

```
print(city.json(ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```
{"name": "Город"}
```

Note that some JSON parsers might not be able to read this file.

If you want to output this string using codepage 866 instead of UTF-8, you might need this code, in order to encode the string from Python's str type into a bytes type:

```
city.json(ensure_ascii=False).encode('cp866')
```

Note that cp866 stands for Code Page 866.